# Bad or inaccessible location specified in external data source

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to save a file from Azure File Storage into Azure SQL Database table varbinary(max) column (store whole content as advised [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36692351/12820222)). I've tried a few times to adjust my SQL query but without success. Here's the code which results in error 'Bad or inaccessible location specified in external data source "my_Azure_Files".' when it invokes OPENROWSET:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mypassword123'
GO

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [https://mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/]
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sas_token_generated_on_azure_portal';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE my_Azure_Files
    WITH (
        LOCATION = 'https://mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/test', 
        CREDENTIAL = [https://mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/],
        TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE
    );

Insert into dbo.myTable(targetColumn)
Select BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET( 
BULK 'test.csv', 
DATA_SOURCE = 'my_Azure_Files', 
SINGLE_BLOB) AS testFile;

CLOSE MASTER KEY;  
GO
```

I'm able to download the test.csv file by a web-browser using the same SAS token and url path. I'm also able to verify that the credential and the external source are successfully created in the database:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+
| data_source_id                                  | name             | location                                            | type_desc               | type             | resource_manager_location | credential_id | database_name | shard_map_name | connection_options | pushdown |
+-------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+
| 65540                                           | my_Azure_Files   | https://mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/test | BLOB_STORAGE            | 05/01/1900 00:00 | NULL                      | 65539         | NULL          | NULL           | NULL               | ON       |
```

```
| name                                            | principal_id     | credential_id                                       | credential_identity     | create_date      | modify_date               | target_type   | target_id     |                |                    |          |
+-------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+
| https://mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/ | 1                | 65539                                               | SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE | 15/07/2020 13:14 | 15/07/2020 13:14          | NULL          | NULL          |                |                    |          |
```

When creating SAS on Azure portal I checked all allowed resource types and all allowed permissions, except 'Delete'. I also removed the leading '?' from SAS to use in the SECRET field.

I've tried variations of `TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE` and `TYPE = HADOOP` as well as `SINGLE_BLOB`, `SINGLE_CLOB` and `SINGLE_NCLOB` parameters.

Please help me solve my problem.

Comment: I've tried to connect to a file in Azure blob container, instead of SMB file shares as I did originally, and it seems to work without problems. So, while this may be a good solution, I'm still keen to know why SMB file sharing isn't working with Azure SQL DB.

Answer (score 1):

By following below steps, able to successfully insert into the target table:

1. While generating the SAS, please select Allowed Resource Type as ‘Container’ and ‘Object’:
   [image]

2. Copy the SAS and use below command:

```
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password@123'
```

3. Use SAS token generated without ‘?’ at the start and create Scoped Credentials:

```
    CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyAzureBlobStorageCredential  WITH IDENTITY = 
    'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',  SECRET = 'sv=2019-10- 
    10XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
```

4. Create External Data Source referencing your blob path:

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage 
    WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'https://mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net'
    , CREDENTIAL= MyAzureBlobStorageCredential 
    );
```

5. Run the insert using OPENROWSET:

```
    Insert into dbo.test(name1)
    Select BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET( 
    BULK 'test/test.csv',
    DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage', 
    SINGLE_BLOB) AS testFile;
```

6. Can also use Bulk insert:

```
    BULK INSERT dbo.test
    FROM 'test/test.csv'
    WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage',
    FORMAT = 'CSV');
```

Assuming table **dbo.test** is already created

Comment: Not working. I've got no problem with Containers. But connecting to Files give me the same error. Does it have anything to do with a pricing plan?

Comment: Also, my account kind is Storage (general purpose v1). Could it be the reason?